# How to setup composite class with microsoft dependency injection?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core

**this is dotnet.core question**

let's say i have class NotifierResolver:

```
public class NotifierResolver : INotifierResolver
{
    private readonly List<INotifier> _notifiers;
    public NotifierResolver(List<INotifier> notifiers)
    {
        _notifiers = notifiers;
    }

    public INotifier Resolve(INotification notification)
    {
        var notifier = _notifiers.Single(h => h.CanNotify(notification));
        if (notifier == null)
        {
            throw new Exception($"could not resolve notification: {notification.GetType()}");
        }
        return notifier;
    }
}
```

How do i setup it's dependencies under service collection ( Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection ) ?

```
var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
    .????
    .AddSingleton<INotifierResolver, NotifierResolver>()
    .BuildServiceProvider();
```

Comment: Your title implies your asking about the Composite design pattern, while `NotifierResolver` is not a Composite; it just wraps a collection of an unrelated type.

Comment: @Steven good catch. It ill be composite the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need to build up the composite at the composition root like below.

```
var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
    .AddTransient<INotifier, SomeNotifier>()
    .AddTransient<INotifier, SomeOtherNotifier>()
    .AddTransient<INotifier, YetAnotherNotifier>()
    .AddSingleton<INotifierResolver, NotifierResolver>(_ 
        => new NotifierResolver(_.GetServices<INotifier>().ToList())//<-- Note GetServices
    )
    .BuildServiceProvider();
```

So assuming you have multiple `INotifier` registered with the service collection, when resolving the `INotifierResolver`, the provider with resolve all the dependencies via `IServiceProvider.GetServices` extension method and inject them into the dependent class.